# Check if attachment is up to date with current document revision in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

in my application I'm post-processing couchdb documents by listening to the changes stream. The scenario is the following:

1. My application gets notified that a document got changed via /db/_changes
2. It fetches the document and checks if the document has an appropriate attachment and if the `revpos` of the attachments is equal to the first part of the document-rev. If for instance the rev looks like this `13-D2JDBS3` then I split the string at the `-` char, take the first match, convert it to a number and compare it to the `revpos` of the attachment.
3. If the above check fails, I generate a PDF and attach it to the document.

This works pretty good so far. But I'm wondering if this is intentional by couchdb's design. Is it safe to rely on this behaviour (that the revpos mirrors the first part of the revision that it belongs to)? I couldn't find anything about this in the docs.

Thanks in advance for any hint on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this intentional and seems to be public and documented API, though the wording could probably use some clarification.

In the [Revisions documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/intro/api.html?highlight=revision#revisions) they say:

> The revision number is the MD5 hash of the transport representation of a document with an N- prefix denoting the number of times a document got updated.

And in the [Attachments documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/api/document/common.html?highlight=revpos#attachments) they say:

> revpos (number): Revision *number* when attachment was added [emphasis theirs]

It's a bit unfortunate that they call the **whole** `_rev` identifier a "revision number" in the former documentation, since it seems clear that the intent within the latter is to highlight just the "N" prefix as the "*number*".

You might consider filing a documentation bug on this, asking them to clarify that revpos will always be the "N" part of the "N- prefix" if that's indeed something they are willing to guarantee.

Comment: Thank you very much for the documentation hints!